# Determine how many memory each process use - Windows

Tags: windows, memory-usage

On a Windows 2019 server equiped with 24 GiB of memory, only about 1 GiB is free.
But when I use `Task Manager` or `Process Explorer`, no process use more than some MiB.

If I add the memory used by each process, the sum is only 3 GiB (I export the data with Process Explorer and do the sum in a spreadsheet).

Total memory: 24 GiB
Used memory: 23 GiB
Swap used: 4 GiB
Sum of each process memory: 3 GiB

I sum `Private Bytes` or `Working Set`, each give a total around 3 GiB.
I know these two indicators are far from optimal, but a better one is not available with these tools. The difference with reality is nearly one order of magnitude!

How can I have a better view of memory usage?
A graphical display as in `WinDirStat` would be very nice, but as this question is a main hassle with Windows, I doubt anything easy exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) to see where you memory is assigned, with a graphical display.

And maybe [PoolMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon) from the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) to help you find leaking drivers, Microsoft provides [examples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon-examples) in the documentation (take a look at `Example 3: Detect Memory Leakage`, i.e. starting `poolmon /p /p /b` and monitoring the output on a regular basis).

Comment: RAMMap gave me the missing information: the memory was heavily consummed by a faulty driver, which was invisible with the usual tools. Many thanks! The only criticism is the lack of details, because I had to guess which driver was involved (which was very easy in this case).